# Access Form SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I had a question which requires theoretical ideas/solutions rather than exact execution plans.

I`m trying to design a MS ACCESS form (I do have some experience with ACCESS but it's been a while and not enough practice), where I can basically compare two tables (table 1 and table 2) and gather a list of names against the other.

Now I know how to do it and get query results. The problem arises when I have multiple other tables that I want to compare with table 1 and some of them have different columns.

This is an ongoing testing process and with new changes introduced monthly/annually, I want an automated form where I can use a button (or something less time consuming than using queries everytime). a Primary key would have been useful but since they don't exist, full names will be the best option.

Another question related to this is, if the excel tables are stored in local server folders, is there a way to quickly retrieve those files into our database without manual imports? Pass-through queries?

I don't mean to throw my work at other people because of laziness, I just want an overview of what approach I can take. Any advice is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: The question isn't really clear.  Are you asking how to query multiple tables from one form?  How are you querying those tables now which prevents this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want an automated form where I can use a button...

This is what [Macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-macros-a39c2a26-e745-4957-8d06-89e0b435aac3) are for... to automate manual tasks that you have to perform.  If you can manually do it with the Access interface, you will probably find a Macro task that does it for you.

If you really want to get fancy you could try your hand at [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) coding to automate some of your manual work. The [DAO library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195520.aspx) allows you to view database metadata which will allow you to write code with some [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) like qualities (VBA doesn't support reflection as it is a scripting language and not OOP). If your metadata is changing constantly, writing this code will be easier said than done... but assuming your foreign keys are labeled properly, you could use a `TableDef` object to search your tables for the corresponding name and then dynamically build a SQL query based on that discovery.

> Another question related to this is, if the excel tables are stored in local server folders, is there a way to quickly retrieve those files into our database without manual imports?

As long as you maintain the same format of your excel files and keep a standard naming convention, you could quite easily automate a process (again using macros) which pulls in a known file from a specific folder.

If things are subject to change you can again use VBA to automate your own streamlined Import process. Microsoft has exposed a lot in Access so you can  even quite easily tap into Window's Common File Dialog (Open and Save pop-up windows) using the [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794.aspx) library to customize your user interaction.

Keep in mind though that to really create something that streamlines your work you are going to have to spend some man-hours coding... so you have to weigh the cost/benefit of the work you'd put in to automate some manual processes.